# Does a page changing inside an iframe change the src of the iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

**What I want to achieve:**

Extracting the current url of an iFrame.

**Search info**

All the sugested "similar questions" return nothing of what I want to achieve here.

**The setup:**

I have an iframe which links to a website. For instance, let's say:

`<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>`

Then, after the user searches for something on google will the iFrame src change to reflect the current URL of the page? For instance:

`https://www.google.pt/search?site=&source=hp&q=test&oq=test`

If not, is there any other way to extract this info?

THanks in advance :)

Comment: can you create an example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Well, I don't think there's much of an example to create, but here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/gknyrrcj/   It's just a simple iframe with a simple src

Comment: when you can make an example with more realistic content we can probably help you but i dont understand your targets

Comment: Three simple steps. Step 1: iframe with an external website. Step 2: Inside the iframe, the user navigates away from the initial url from the iframe src. Step 3: I want to be able to access the url of the current page displayed on the iframe. Can't get more realistic than this...

Comment: aha I cant help you.

Comment: No, there is no way for you to get that info, because of the Same Origin Policy. (Only if the page containing the iframe and the pages loaded into it were from the same domain this would be possible.)

Comment: so you could set the target from the link to your main-frame or you analyse all the html code from the iframe and set the target over all links, but in a simple way its not possible...